# AlarmManager doesn't start my Receiver

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager

I am setting an `AlarmaManager` event, but my `BroadcastReceiver` doesn't catch it:

```
String task_uuid = UUID_Generator.getUUID();
Intent task_intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),AlarmReciever.class);
task_intent.putExtra("task_id", task_uuid);
task_intent.putExtra("test", 10101010);
PendingIntent operation = 
PendingIntent.getActivity(getBaseContext(),0, task_intent, 0);
AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getBaseContext().getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
long alarm_time = dateTime.getTimeInMillis();
alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, alarm_time, operation);
```

**AlarmReceiver**:

```
    public class AlarmReciever extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("test!!!");
        try {
            SMSUtills.sendSMS("0504235325", "נסיון תזמון");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Have you register your  **AlarmReciever** in your Maifest.xml file?

Comment: Yes: <receiver android:name=".AlarmReciever"/>

Comment: show your whole manifest file, not excerpt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem is that I didn't specify wake lock permission in my manifast.

Answer (score 0):

Add this:

```
startActivity(task_intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have used this code in my project it's work fine:

```
Intent myIntent1 = new Intent(PrayerTimeActivity.this, AlarmReceiverFri.class); 
                    AlarmManager alarmManager1 = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);                    
PendingIntent pendingIntent1 = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(PrayerTimeActivity.this,0, myIntent1, 0); 

                    alarmManager1.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,Calendar_Object.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent1);
```

and the receiver class is:

```
    import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;

public class AlarmReceiverFri extends BroadcastReceiver {

     @Override
     public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
     // When our Alaram time is triggered , this method will be excuted (onReceive)
     // We're invoking a service in this method which shows Notification to the User


      Intent myIntent = new Intent(context, NotificationServiceFri.class);
      context.startService(myIntent);
    }

}
```

and in AndroidManifest.xml also contain

```
<receiver android:name=".AlarmReceiverFri" />
```

Thanks!!!

If my answer will help you then don't forget to accept this answer. :)